# How to sort dates in asp.net ListBox using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using following jquery script to add dates into listbox, all works fine but i am not able to sort listbox.

i have used following script line to dates but it doesn't work.

```
var sortedList = $.makeArray($("#lstVisitDates option")).sort(function (a, b) 
{ return Date.parse($(a).text()) < Date.parse ($(b).text()) ? -1 : 1; });
```

jQuery script

```
function checkValue(el) {
var txt = $("span[id$=spVisitDates] input[type=text]"); 
var svc = $(txt).val()   
var lst = $('#lstVisitDates');
var options = $('#lstVisitDates option'); 
var alreadyExist = false;
$(options).each(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == svc) {
        alert("Item alread exists");
        alreadyExist = true;
        return;
    }
});
if (!alreadyExist)

$(lst).find("option").attr("selected", false);
$(lst).append('<option value="' + svc + '" selected="selected">' + svc + '</option>');


var sortedList = $.makeArray($("#lstVisitDates option")).sort(function (a, b) { return Date.parse  ($(a).text()) < Date.parse ($(b).text()) ? -1 : 1; });
// Clear the options and add the sorted ones    
$(lst).empty().html(sortedList);

return false;

}
```

Date are in following format;

01-April-2013

04-March-2014

Html after rendering

```
<select id="lstVisitDates" style="width:220px;" multiple="multiple" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tabContainer$tabScopes$Scopes$lstVisitDates" size="4">
    <option value="15-Apr-2014"></option>
    <option value="02-Apr-2014"></option>
    <option selected="selected" value="08-Apr-2014"></option>
</select>
```

ADDED:

This works fine but it doesn't sort month and year just dates.
var sortedList = $.makeArray($("#lstVisitDates option")).sort(function (a, b) { return $(a).text() < $(b).text() ? -1 : 1; });

Comment: could you post the html dom structure

Comment: do you mean actual html or html after rendering?

Comment: the html after rendering or you could create a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: i have added the html in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was two flaw in your code

1. You should have used `.val()` instead of `.text()`.
2. The parsing of the date was not current as it was resulting in `NAN`.

**Jquery Code:**

```
//module to parse the date "dd-mmm-yyyy"
function parseDMY(s) {
     return new Date(s.replace(/^(\d+)\W+(\w+)\W+/, '$2 $1 '));
}

$("#lstVisitDates").html($("#lstVisitDates option").sort(function (a, b) {
    return parseDMY($(a).val()) < parseDMY($(b).val()) ? -1 : 1;
}));
```

**LIVE DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/w3jfF/91/

Happy Coding :)